# Time complexity of simple if else statement

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I am a new learner and am unable to understand time complexity of if else statement. I have read online that time complexity for if-else is given in both max and min terms.

As per my understanding both max and min would be O(1), but some websites share otherwise and I am unable to understand it. Thank you.

```
Function copy(number)
  If number == 3
     console.log("number is 3");
  Else
     console.log("number is not 3");
```

Comment: It is O(1). I have never heard of Time complexity of if else statements. You can speed up the process by having the most likely outcome be the first if-condition though. And it only matters if the condition is tested multiple times. If other web sites share otherwise, please share the source, and others can have a look at it as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm complexity: if/else under for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164749/algorithm-complexity-if-else-under-for-loop)

Comment: @John These are the notes, I read from, it says, the complexity should be O(1) and O(n)

[link] (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20sequence%201,would%20be%20O(N).&text=Every%20time%20the%20outer%20loop,O(N%20*%20M)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things clear, from the [link you posted in the comment](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Evernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20sequence%201,would%20be%20O(N).&text=Every%20time%20the%20outer%20loop,O), it says:

**if-then-else statements**

```js
if (condition) {
    sequence of statements 1
}
else {
    sequence of statements 2
}
```

> Here, either sequence 1 will execute, or sequence 2 will execute.
> Therefore, the worst-case time is the slowest of the two
> possibilities: max(time(sequence 1), time(sequence 2)). For example,
> if sequence 1 is O(N) and sequence 2 is O(1) the worst-case time for
> the whole if-then-else statement would be O(N).

Which means that you account for the worst time complexity of one of the **sequences**, *not* the if-else-statement itself.

Let me give another example

```js
function foo(){
  if (bar) {
    return 'bar'; // O(1)
  } else {
    return someArray.map((a) => a+1); // O(n)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I am able to understood, the concept, why O(n) is taken.